# In subscribe assign value to variable.once it is assigned, next method should executed

Tags: angular, angular8

I need to assign a value to variable  in subscribe and that variable is passed to one method. Once it is assigned I need to execute that method.Right now before assigning it is taking default value to that method and Getting executed

Example:

```
loginIntoApp(){
  this.userService.getIfuserPresent(this.login.firstName,this.login.password).pipe().
       subscribe(data=> {
        this.hasUser = data;
        console.log(`Logging into App` +this.hasUser);
     }
     );

     this.fireEvent(this.hasUser);

  }
```

So here Before assigning value to hasUser in subscribe, next method(fireEvent) is getting Executed, so it results in fail of second method.variable in subscribe is assigned after execution of second method. It taking more time in returning value from subscribe. So do we have any Operator in subscribe to wait the next method exectuion till it get assigned.

Comment: You can improve this question by adding any code you've actually tried and an explanation of what is going wrong. Without that, this question is too open-ended and merits a downvote.

Comment: @AntoineB I agree, it is much clearer now that the user responded to my request for more detail by adding useful code. If you check the edit history you will find that your comment was unnecessary.

Comment: @NathanBeck You're right, I arrived when it already had the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, `subscribe()` is asynchronous, it means that `this.fireEvent(this.hasUser);` will be called before your service returns the answer.

You have to call the next line in the result of the subscribe call:

```
loginIntoApp(){
    this.userService.getIfuserPresent(this.login.firstName,this.login.password).pipe().
        subscribe(data=> {
            this.hasUser = data;
            console.log(`Logging into App` +this.hasUser);

            this.fireEvent(this.hasUser);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: @user12303682 Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted by ticking the V sign next to it.